# Ito's formula for Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Suppose ($Y_t$) is a rate 1 Poisson process, and consider the jump process $Z_t=Y_{\int_0^tf(X_s)ds}$ for some non-negative process $X_s$. What would be the quadratic variation of $Z$, and how would one write Ito's formula for $Z$? Please give references to books/ theorems used if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Poisson process, the quadratic variation is just $N(t)$. For $Z_t$, the quadratic variation is just
$N(\int_0^tf(X_s)ds)$, if $f$ is positive. Without positive assumption, the 'time' $\int_0^tf(X_s)ds$ can be negative

Comment: Thanks. What would be the Ito formula for $Z_t$?

Comment: Seems to me this is not a situation that Ito formula can be applied to directly. $Z_t$ is not something that can be written as a function of $Y_t$.  Also, you need to change the filtration, cause $Z_t$ may not adapt to the Poisson filtration.

Comment: Yes I thought so. Could you or anyone else help with still getting a version of Ito's formula for this case?